# Text and picture not align vertical

Tags: html, css

I am using the foundation framework for making emails. I have made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fx1tboyr/) that illustrates my problem. I need the text to vertical align with the banner-picture. At the moment the text is going a little bit to the right of the picture. I cannot understand why?

An example is on my website here: [Example Site](http://mimsi.dk/kunde-bekraeftelse-testing.html)

I have tried to set a `text-align: left !important;`, `padding:0px;`, `margin-left:0px;`, but nothing is working.

The relevant HTML code:

```
<table class="row background-color__yellow">
    <tr>
        <td class="center" align="center">
            <center>
                <table class="container">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper last">
                            <table class="row background-color__yellow">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last">
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-top: 30px;">
                                                        <h3 class="velkomst">Kære @Model.Order.FirstName @Model.Order.LastName</h3>
                                                        <br>
                                                        <span class="text-left small-text-left">
                                                            Tak for din reservation på @(Model.Order.Store.Name). Har du spørgsmål, er du velkommen til at kontakte os. Vi har åbent alle hverdage mellem kl. 8.30 og kl. 16.00.
                                                        </span>
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <span class="text-left small-text-left">
                                                        Vi ønsker dig et rigtig dejligt ophold
                                                        </span><br><br>
                                                        <span class="text-left small-text-left">
                                                        Med venlig hilsen
                                                        </span>
                                                        <br>
                                                        <span class="text-left small-text-left">
                                                        Company
                                                        </span>
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <span class="text-left small-text-left">
                                                        PS: Det er gratis at blive medlem af vores gæsteklub Benefits, hvor du optjener point på ophold og får adgang til et væld af gode tilbud.
                                                        </span>
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <span class="text-left small-text-left">
                                                            <a href="https://www.test.dk/benefits/login/" target="_blank">Klik her for at læse mere og tilmelde dig</a>
                                                        </span>
                                                        <br /><br />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The table you use for the text content is inside a th that has padding on the left and right. That is the only space I can see and it's coming from your stylesheed. Either overwrite or remove it.

Comment: Also add the relevant css.

Comment: @Gezzasa: How would it be possible to solve that? `.th {padding-left:!important;}` ?

Comment: @M375 Apologies for the late reply. Did you custom build this mailer or is it created dynamically? If you are custom building it you can simply remove the class selector from the TH to remove the padding.